# Subsetting ffdf in loop

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

I'm trying to subset a very large ffdf object in a loop using ffbase, but I'm getting the error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.hi") : no applicable method for 'as.hi' applied to an object of
class "NULL"
```

I'm running this code on an ssh with large amounts of memory available. Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
# totalD is an ffdf with columns ID, TS, and TD, each with 288,133,589 rows. ID consists
# of integers. TS is a column of integer timestamps with second precision. TD is of type
# double. Uid3 is an integer vector consisting of the 1205 unique entries of totalD$ID.

# H_times creates a matrix of the sum of the entries in TD traveled in each hour
H_times <- function(totalD, Uid3) {

    # hours is the number of unique hours of the experiment
    hours <- length(unique(subset(totalD$TS, totalD$TS %% 3600 == 0)))-1

    # bH is used as a counter in a the following loops
    bH <- min(unique(subset(totalD$TS, totalD$TS %% 3600 == 0)))

    # sum_D_matrix is the output
    sum_D_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = hours, ncol = length(Uid3))

    for(i in 1:length(Uid3)) {
        Bh <- bH
        for(j in 1:hours) {
            sum_D_matrix[j,i] <- sum(subset(totalD$TD, totalD$TS >= Bh & totalD$TS < (Bh + 3600) & totalD$ID == Uid3[i]))
            Bh <- Bh + 3600
        }
    }
    save(sum_D_matrix, file = "sum_D_matrix)
}

H_times(totalD, Uid3)
```

I tried to implement the fix that jwijffels suggested in the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427259/how-to-subset-a-large-data-frame-ffdf-in-r-by-date) question, but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the line:

```
sum_D_matrix[j,i] <- sum(subset(totalD$TD, 
    totalD$TS >= Bh & totalD$TS < (Bh + 3600) & totalD$ID == Uid3[i]))
```

Where the selection can be empty. One of the problems with `ff` is that it can not handle empty vectors. The size of an vector/`ffdf` should always be >= 1. Perhaps this should be handled by `subset.ff`. However, what `subset.ff` should then return is unclear.

You can use the following work-around:

```
sel <- totalD$TS >= Bh & totalD$TS < (Bh + 3600) & totalD$ID == Uid3[i]
sel <- ffwhich(sel, sel)
if (is.null(sel)) {
  sum_D_matrix[j,i] <- 0
} else {
  sum_D_matrix[j,i] <- sum(totalD$TD[sel])
}
```

`ffwhich` returns `NULL` when the resulting vector would be empty (as I mentioned it cannot return an vector with length 0).

**Side note**

The way you are using subset is actually a bit strange. One of the reasons to use `subset` is to simplify notation by getting rid of all the `totalD$` . The more 'usual' way of using it would be:

```
sum_D_matrix[j,i] <- sum(subset(totalD, TS >= Bh & TS < (Bh + 3600) & ID == Uid3[i], 
    TD, drop=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use your code and variations of it, I get `Error in which(eval(e, nl, envir)) : argument to 'which' is not logical`.